# What DT Swiss Valve and Tubeless Tape fit DT Swiss Wheels 2291335 and 2569868?

Tags: tubeless, valves, rim-tape, dtswiss, canyon

I recently bought the Endurace CF SL 7 eTAP bike and it came with DT Swiss wheels.

DT Swiss front wheel 2291335
DT Swiss rear wheel 2569868

What DT Swiss valve would I use for my front and rear wheels?
Also, what DT Swiss tubeless tape would fit my front and rear wheels?

Answer (score 1):

For your Endurance LN wheelset you need 2x the tubeless valve with the item number: TVVXA32S23757S.

The wheel is already fitted with the 25mm tubeless tape at the factory, but the tape should be checked for damage before the conversion and replaced if necessary.